# Spring-4 - Refactoring use of instanceof for calling appropriate method

Tags: java, spring-4

I have below set of interfaces and classes.
Note the `doSomething` method. It has to check for the instance of the object before calling the interface method on it. I would like to avoid that, as it involves changing this method whenever a new Vehicle is added. What is the best way of doing this in Spring?

```
class SomeService {
  @Autowired
  VehicleRepairService<Car> carRepariService;

  @Autowired
  VehicleRepairService<Truck> truckRepairService;


  public void doSomething(String vehicleId) {
     Vehicle vehicle = getVehicle(vehicleId);
     if(vehicle instanceof Car) {
        carRepairService.repair(vehicle);
     } else {
        truckRepairService.repair(vehicle);
     }
  }
}

interface VehicleRepairService<T extends Vehicle> {
  void repair(T vehicle);
}

class CarRepairService implements VehicleRepairService<Car> {
    @Autowired
    SomeDependency some;

    void repair(Car vehicle) {
    .......
    }
}

class TruckRepairService implements VehicleRepairService<Car> {
  @Autowired
  DifferentDependency different;

   void repair(Truck vehicle) {
    .......
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since none of the answers has a generic solution. Spring allows to inject all implementations of a type. The solution below is not tested I wrote it in a text editor. It can be improved by making VehicleRepairService an abstract class and use for example ResolvableType retrieve the generic type in this abstract class. Than it is not necessary anymore to implement the getType method in every instance.

```
class SomeService  {

    @Autowired
    private List<VehicleRepairService> vehicleRepairServices;


    public void doSomething(String vehicleId) {
        Vehicle vehicle = getVehicle(vehicleId);
        for(VehicleRepairService vehicleRepairService:vehicleRepairServices){
            if(vehicle.getClass().equals(vehicleRepairService.getType())){
                vehicleRepairService.repair(vehicle);
            }
        }
    }

    public Vehicle getVehicle(String id){
        return new Truck();
    }
}

interface VehicleRepairService<T extends Vehicle> {
    void repair(T vehicle);

    Class<T> getType();
}

class CarRepairService implements VehicleRepairService<Car> {

    public void repair(Car vehicle) {
    }

    @Override
    public Class<Car> getType() {
        return Car.class;
    }
}

class TruckRepairService implements VehicleRepairService<Truck> {

    public void repair(Truck vehicle) {
    }

    @Override
    public Class<Truck> getType() {
        return Truck.class;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks to be the most closest desirable solution if combined with `ResolvableType`. I don't see any other better solution/approach either. This really helps in maintaining open-close principle.

Comment: It's fully generic theoretically you could create an implementation that acts as a dispatcher so you have this list thing in only one class

Comment: In my humble opinion it is not generic, niether it retains open-close principle. Because you bind car to service by exact type, so you are comparing types. It just hides the problem, it doesn't solve it. Next programmer will need to decode your idea, the getType is unnecesary, what is it for? Does this method need to be public? Do you plan to make more places in your code where you compare the types? What if the policy of binding car to service will change?

Comment: As I wrote in the comment you could create an implementation of VehiceRepairService that contains the for loop part and you only use this class. The public method is then not necessary, because of the inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

In general where you have `instanceof` together with `switch` or `if .. else if ..`s you could think about using the [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). For your code it would mean something like this:

```
interface Vehicle
{
    public interface Visitor<T>
    {
        T visit(Car car);
        T visit(Truck truck);
    }

     <T> T accept(Visitor<T> visitor);
}

class Car implements Vehicle
{

    @Override
    public <T> T accept(Visitor<T> visitor)
    {
        return visitor.visit(this);
    }    
};

class Truck implements Vehicle
{
    @Override
    public <T> T accept(Visitor<T> visitor)
    {
        return visitor.visit(this);
    }
};
```

You can then on the places where you need a distinction between the specific instances create a new Visitor, either inline or as separate class:

```
Vehicle.Visitor<Void> repairVisitor = new Vehicle.Visitor<Void>()
{

    @Override
    public Void visit(Car car)
    {
        carRepairService.repair(car);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Void visit(Truck truck)
    {
        truckRepairService.repair(truck);
        return null;
    }
};
vehicle.accept(repairVisitor);
```

Please note that I made the visitor generic. You could then also have Visitors returning something.

Comment: And if I add a new Vehicle, then I will have to modify the Visitor interface. That is not what I am looking for. I want to follow open-close principle.

Comment: Yes, you are right, if the number of different Vehicles often changes this is not ideal. On the other hand you have to find every occurrence of `if ..instanceof.. else..` by hand whereas here the code won't compile until you have extended the visitors. The alternative would be to restructure the code to give the repairService as dependency of every vehicle.

Comment: `Vehicle` is an Entity, not a Service. So injecting the repairService in `vehicle` is not ideal